# Concatenate tf.range in Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, concatenation

I would like to create a Keras model and add sequencial number to a input tensor.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(3, 3))

seq = tf.range(3)
seq = tf.reshape(seq, (3, 1))

concatenated = Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_layer, seq])

additional_layer = Dense(4, activation="relu")(concatenated)
...
```

The problem is that input layer is of a size `(none, 3,3)` and the seq is of a size `(3,1)`

Even if I transform it to a

```
seq = tf.reshape(seq, (1, 3, 1))
```

the concatenation will give me an error that shapes don't match.

How to add sequential numbers to every row that will go into the Input layer?

---

## Try the Solution from the answer:

```
a = np.array([
    [[10.0,20.0,30.0], [20.0,30.0,40.0], [40.0,50.0,50.0]],
    [[10.0,20.0,30.0], [20.0,30.0,40.0], [40.0,50.0,50.0]],
    [[10.0,20.0,30.0], [20.0,30.0,40.0], [40.0,50.0,50.0]]
])
x_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3, 3))
seq = tf.range(3, dtype=tf.float32)
seq = tf.reshape(seq, (1, 3, 1))
concatenated = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x:tf.concat([x, seq], axis=-1))(input_layer)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=concatenated)

print(model(x_tf))
```

and I get:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'lambda_5' (type Lambda).

{{function_node __wrapped__ConcatV2_N_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} ConcatOp : Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal: shape[0] = [3,3,3] vs. shape[1] = [1,3,1] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat

Call arguments received by layer 'lambda_5' (type Lambda):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(3, 3, 3), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3, 3))
seq = tf.range(3, dtype=tf.float32)
seq = tf.reshape(seq, (1, 3, 1))
concatenated = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x:tf.concat([x, seq], axis=-1))

# print(concatenated(tf.ones((1,3,3))))
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
# array([[[1., 1., 1., 0.],
#         [1., 1., 1., 1.],
#         [1., 1., 1., 2.]]], dtype=float32)>
```

In few words, `tf.keras.layers.Lambda` is a layer that is called during the forward pass and just applies the lambda function that is given... inside which, you do nothing more than the concatenation that you were asking.

Updated answer for varying batch size:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.array([
    [[10.0,20.0,30.0], [20.0,30.0,40.0], [40.0,50.0,50.0]],
    [[10.0,20.0,30.0], [20.0,30.0,40.0], [40.0,50.0,50.0]],
    [[10.0,20.0,30.0], [20.0,30.0,40.0], [40.0,50.0,50.0]]
])
x_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3, 3))
seq = tf.repeat(tf.range(3, dtype=tf.float32)[None, ...], repeats=tf.shape(input_layer)[0], axis=0)[..., None]
concatenated = tf.concat([input_layer, seq], axis=-1)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=concatenated)
print(model(x_tf))
```

Comment: Hi, I try your solution but it gives me an error... I updated my question and paste code with error there

Comment: @MarkoZadravec you accepted the answer... so I suppose the error is now gone?...

Comment: Yes, The error is gone :D But I have one question regarding this answer: If I understand correctly this will create sequence tensor in a size of a batch size?

Comment: The size of the batch size depends on your input to your model. In your case, it is 3.

Comment: @MarkoZadravec I agree with AloneTogether, the BatchSize is determined by either how you call fit, or the tensor you provide the network... the broadcasting of the tensor will concat that tensor to all batches without any need to specify it